# easeljs Sepia and Grayscale

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I am looking at using EaselJS to do some image manipulation through JavaScript, does anyone have any examples of how to apply a Sepia and, separately, a Grayscale filter to an image using this library?
http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS

In case you are wondering, I have been looking at many alternative libraries, but none seem to work as well across browsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use createjs.ColorMatrixFilter() to apply color filters to your bitmaps**

Here are filters for Grayscale and Sepia:

```
var Grayscale = new createjs.ColorMatrixFilter([
        0.30,0.30,0.30,0,0, // red component
        0.30,0.30,0.30,0,0, // green component
        0.30,0.30,0.30,0,0, // blue component
        0,0,0,1,0  // alpha
]);
myEaselBitmap.filters = [Grayscale];


var Sepia = new createjs.ColorMatrixFilter([
    0.39, 0.77, 0.19, 0, 0, // red component
    0.35, 0.68, 0.17, 0, 0, // green component
    0.27, 0.53, 0.13, 0, 0, // blue component
    0, 0, 0, 1, 0  // alpha
]);
myEaselBitmap.filters = [Sepia];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a working example of also rotating an image 90 degrees? I mention the degrees because the image doesn't have to be resized, the width and height just get swapped.

Comment: That is excellent. Now that you've been so helpful, if you don't mind one more question. Is it possible to achieve the same thing without a canvas? I'm wondering about < IE9 versions

Comment: For IE<9, you can use excanvas.js which taps into IE's native VML to create a "canvas".  The code is here: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions